# Unable to make typescript recognize typing

Tags: typescript, types, react-datepicker

I am working on this project and we were required to translate all files created from React Javascript to React Typescript, but being a begginer on type annotations, I have had some struggles, especially with 3rd party packages and libs.

I am using ReactDatePicker to get the user inputted date (written or selected) and moment lib to parse it, together with formik in a multi step form, so users can see, edit and create all in one component. In the latest file I have tampered with, typescript complains that the 'string' value I am working with cannot be assigned to 'Date', although I am typing it as Date | string on its interface as I code it.

This is the interface, which is in an external file:

```
export interface BaseRelationType extends BaseEntity {
  institutional_relation_approval: Date | string | any,
}
```

And this is the component accessing it:

```
import {
  getIn, useFormikContext,
} from 'formik';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import { FormikStep } from 'components/Stepper/Step';
import DateInput, { DateInputProps } from 'components/DateInput/DateInput';
import { RelationFormType } from 'types/relations';

export interface DateStepProps {
  validationSchema: Object,
  innerRef: boolean,
}

const RelationTypeStep: React.FC<DateStepProps> = ({
   innerRef, validationSchema,
}) => {
  const {
    values, errors, touched, setFieldValue,
  } = useFormikContext<RelationFormType>();

  return (
    <FormikStep>
      <Row>
          <DatePicker
            selected={values.institutional_relation_approval ? Date.parse(values.institutional_relation_approval) : ''}
            placeholderText="DD/MM/YYYY"
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
            name="institutional_relation_approval"
            disabled={isView}
            onChange={((date) => {
              setFieldValue('institutional_relation_approval', date);
              console.log(date);
            })}
          />
    </FormikStep>
  );
};

export default RelationTypeStep;
```

and the error I am getting:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ReactDatePickerProps | Readonly<ReactDatePickerProps>): ReactDatePicker', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReactDatePickerProps, context: any): ReactDatePicker', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined'.  TS2769
```

Am I annotating this type correctly? What does this no overload error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which line prompt the error.

From what I see, the selected property should be accepting `Date` or `null` only while
`Date.parse()` returns number instead of `Date` and the else case return an empty string instead of null so the type is incompatible.

```js
selected={
    values.institutional_relation_approval
    ? new Date(values.institutional_relation_approval) // return Date object
    : null // return null if no value provided
}
```

Comment: It is this line:

            selected={values.institutional_relation_approval ? Date.parse(values.institutional_relation_approval) : ''}

, exactly the one you gave me in your answer
, forgive me for not making it clear. i will try your suggestion

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help!